# permanently keep a edited website, locally

Tags: web, editing

I would like to keep a copy of a website, which I have edited saved locally to my machine, but so when I type in the url it comes up as the webpage I edited. It is not my website, I don't have access to the server but I would like my own edited copy of the website. Something like greasemoneky but which is easier to setup and use but also able to be able to sync with chrome if possible.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need a web server on your machine.  Depends on the requirements of the website and what OS you have.  XAMPP is one good option.

Comment: Are you using any CMS such as Drupal, Wordpress, etc?

Comment: @dan1111 just a regular website and I am on a chromebook but I could use a windows 7 or macbook if required, I have them all

Comment: @KarthikSampath It is not my website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an entry in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file so that the URL redirects to your own computer?

```
127.0.0.1       www.google.com
```

Then you have to have a webserver installed with the local page bound to the url.

Comment: But still it’s the solution to redirect the URL to his local computer. And then how he solves it with the WWW server is up to himself. He might be using Apache, IIS or some other program. The question doesn’t mention that. So a minus on my post aint fair. It´s still a good solution.

Comment: :) Added the part with webserver installed bound to the URL.

Comment: You and I pretty much reached the same conclusion. So I dunno why you got a minus... but you definitely get a plus from me. I gotta respect the whole 'great minds think alike' business :D

Comment: He removed the minus after I updated the post with the webserver part. And now you got a vote up too. =)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're intending to use this for. Hopefully not anything shady. 
To redirect any website url on your local machine you could set up parental controls.

There's plenty of ways to do it and it depends on your browser/operating system/modem.
You can locally redirect files via your computer's local hostfile.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pTvYMCMtKU

If you really want to get serious about it, then you could set up a little local DNS hijack with a service like OpenDNS. An even more extreme option would be something like DNSMASQ http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html.

Answer (score 0):

After you finish editing the website,press ctrl+s and that will save a copy of the website.

Comment: Will that save the current browser modifications or the original?